# Dataweave 2.0 : How to remove items from inside an array based on values of a field?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have the following input, And I want to remove all entries under the same name, where the sum of chocolates for for two items is zero.

```
[
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : 5,
"date" : "2021-01-01"
},
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : -5,
"date" : "2021-01-02"
},
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : 15,
"date" : "2021-01-03"
},
{
"name" : "DEF",
"chocolates" : 7,
"date" : "2021-01-01"
}
]
```

Expected Output :

```
[{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : 15,
"date" : "2021-01-03"
},
{
"name" : "DEF",
"chocolates" : 7,
"date" : "2021-01-01"
}
]
```

Data weave code that I tried is :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce ((item, accumulator = [] ) ->
    if(!isEmpty(accumulator)) accumulator reduce ((item2, agg = []) -> 
        if(item.name == item2.name and item.chocolates == -(item2.chocolates))
        (agg << item) << item2
        else 
        log(agg)
    )

    else accumulator << item
 )
```

But the out put i am getting is :

```
[
  {
    "name": "DEF",
    "chocolates": 7,
    "date": "2021-01-01"
  }
]
```

Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks

Comment: You said you want to remove sum of chocolates for two items with same name is 0. But in the example the ABC has 3 entries. Can you clarify what happens in that case? Do you need this `get sum of all the chocolates with same name and then remove the items that has 0 chocolates`?, because the example looks like that only.

Comment: "the sum of chocolates for for two items is zero" Is the condition any two items with the same name, or any consecutive two items with the same name?

Comment: what should be the output of this  `[{"name": "A","chocolates": -10},{"name": "A","chocolates": -5},{"name": "A","chocolates": -2},{"name": "D","chocolates": 7},{"name": "A","chocolates": 15},{"name": "A","chocolates": 7}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very interesting use case. There are several ways to resolve it, I always like using array deconstruct and construct as I think is very declarative. For this I created two function one is a filterFirst that removes the first element that doesn't match a given criteria.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays

fun filterFirst<T>(elements: Array<T>,criteria: (source:T) -> Boolean): Array<T> = do {
    elements  match {
        case [x ~ xs] ->  
            if(criteria(x))
                [x ~ filterFirst(xs, criteria)]
            else
                xs    
        case [] -> []
    }
}

fun removeWhen<T>(elements: Array<T>,  criteria: (source:T, target:T) -> Boolean) = do {
    fun loop(head, carrier) = do {
        var filteredCriteria = carrier filterFirst ((item) -> !criteria(head, item)) //Filter just the first element that matches 
        var toRemove = sizeOf(filteredCriteria) != sizeOf(carrier) //An element has matched so we don't 
        ---
        filteredCriteria  match {
            case [x ~ xs] ->  
                if(toRemove)
                    loop(x, xs)
                else 
                    [head ~ loop(x, xs)]   
            case [] -> 
                if(toRemove)
                    []
                else
                    [head]    
        }                    
    }        
    ---
    elements match {
        case [] -> []
        case [x ~ xs] -> loop( x, xs)
    }
}   
---
flatten(
    payload 
        groupBy ((item, index) -> item.name)
        pluck ((chocolates, key, index) -> 
            chocolates removeWhen ((source, target) -> (source.chocolates + target.chocolates) == 0)
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear on the requirement. Assuming that the `sum of chocolates for two items is zero` for the consecutive items with the same name, following script could work

To support the scenario described in the comment, it requires a very similar approach given by OP.

`Removed the previous answer and updated one that covers most of the  scenarios`

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
---
do {
 var out = payload reduce ((item, accumulator = 
    {
        final: [], 
        interim: []
    } ) ->
            if(!isEmpty(accumulator.interim)) 
                (accumulator.interim) reduce ((item2, agg = []) -> 
                    if(item.name == item2.name and item.chocolates == -(item2.chocolates))
                    {
                        final: accumulator.final,
                        interim: []                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        final: (accumulator.final << item2),
                        interim: drop(accumulator.interim,1) << item          
                    }
                        
                )
            else {
                final: accumulator.final,
                interim: accumulator.interim << item
            }
        )
    ---
    out.final ++ out.interim
}
```

Comment: It will give an extra item if the corresponding chocolates are in even number. Test with this `[{"name": "ABC","chocolates": 5},{"name": "ABC","chocolates": -5},{"name": "DEF","chocolates": 7}]`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun duplicateItems(payloadOne, payloadTwo) =
    do {
        var removeObjs = 
            payloadOne map (item, index) -> 
                payloadTwo map (item2, index2) -> 
                    if(item.name == item2.name and item.chocolates == -(item2.chocolates))
                        [item, item2]
                    else
                        [{}]
        ---
        flatten(flatten(removeObjs)) filter ((item, index) -> !isEmpty(item))
    }
---
payload -- duplicateItems(payload, payload)
```

I thought it was better to work based on the payload, because you may have "duplicate" values anywhere.
Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "chocolates": 15,
    "date": "2021-01-03"
  },
  {
    "name": "DEF",
    "chocolates": 7,
    "date": "2021-01-01"
  }
]
```

Comment: This code fails if we have repeated entries. eg. Trying with the input [
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : 5,
"date" : "2021-01-01"
},
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : -5,
"date" : "2021-01-02"
},
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : 15,
"date" : "2021-01-01"
},
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : -15,
"date" : "2021-01-02"
},
{
"name" : "ABC",
"chocolates" : 15,
"date" : "2021-01-03"
},
{
"name" : "DEF",
"chocolates" : 7,
"date" : "2021-01-01"
}
] Gives only one object DEF